# Please check old PHP code for putting variable values into url

Tags: php, url

I have been working on a coding problem for some pages I inherited where the values of two variables are not showing up in the URL of the next page.

The code written by the author, which is probably quite old is

```
"completeyourorder.php?p=" . $p . "&service=" . $service;
```

as far as I can tell from my research there should be at least an echo in there

"completeyourorder.php?p=" echo . $p . "&service=" . $service;

or maybe I am missing much more than that.

I'd be grateful for a bit of education on this as I am a newbie and have not been able to find an answer despite many hours of tickering and reading.

Thanks

UPDATE:

PAGE 1

```
<form action="send-order.php" method="post">
<p>Name<br /><input name="clientname" value="<?echo $clientname;?>" type="text" style="width: 350px;" /></p>

<p><br /><input type="hidden" name="service" value="<?
echo $_GET['service'];
?>" />

<input type="hidden" name="p" value="<?
echo $_GET['p'];
?>"
 />
<input type="submit" value="Order now" /></p>
 </form>
```

PAGE 2

```
$go = "completeyourorder.php?p=" . $p . "&service=" . $service;
return header("location:$go");
```

Let me know if you need anything more

SOLVED:

Brilliant thanks it works!  I see now that my error was assuming that I could use the variable values in the location: completeyourorder..... on page 2 without having used $_POST earlier in the code on the same page.  Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Yes, that code does nothing.  We'd need to see the surrounding code to see the context, though.

Comment: If the complete line is something like `$url = "completeyourorder.php?p=" . $p . "&service=" . $service;` then you're just looking at concatenated strings, nothing special.

Comment: OK, so if I wanted www....../completeyourorder.php?p=55&service=Angel Reading how would I code that if $p is 55 and $service is Angel Reading?  Thanks

Comment: looks like that guy assumed register_globals = on ? Tried to use $_POST['p'] instead of $p and so on?

Comment: yes I think he did, it is old code

Comment: Needs input validation.  I see several injection flaws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You recently asked a similar question regarding $_GET vars.

In this case, it looks like you're building a string to echo out in a link or something. So perhaps this is the what you may be experiencing: (only an example)

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['p']))
{
    $p = $_GET['p'];
}

if(isset($_GET['service']))
{
    $service = $_GET['service'];
}

//defaults in case they are not set
$p or $p = 1; //assuming p = page
$service or $service = 'laundry'; //since I don't know what service refers to

$link = "completeyourorder.php?p=" . $p . "&service=" . $service;

?>

<a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">string to click on</a>
```

Where in this example you can see that you are expecting to build the $link var based on the $_GET vars "p" and "service" and if they do not exist, default to the standard set of page 1 and service of "laundry"

Obviously you would tailor this to fit your needs, but you will need to provide more info for a better, more relevant answer.

**EDIT**

As per your edit, the basic answer is that your form should be populating the vars for $p and $service, so the revised code would be like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['p']) && isset($_POST['service']))
{
    $p = $_POST['p'];
    $service = $_POST['service'];

    // do some kind of post processing here
    // possibly do some kind of filtering to ensure the post vars are sanitized 

    header("location: completeyourorder.php?p=" . $p . "&service=" . $service);
    exit;
}
?>
```

isset is not necessary on both, but you can change that to reflect your preferred choice for verifying post data. Some just do:

```
if(!empty($_POST))
```

Comment: Yes I am still trying to establish whether I have an error in setting the variable or doing something with the variable.  I am fairly confident now that setting the variable is OK

Comment: Brilliant thanks it works!  I see now that my error was assuming that I could use the variable value in the location: completeyourorder..... on page 2 without having used $_POST earlier in the code on the same page.  I haven't used the isset yet but for now the process works so I am happy, thanks to everyone!

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip.  It was this answer which made me click what was missing (even though it was staring me in the face).

Answer (score 1):

What you have shown here is just building part of a string.  In php the period is the concatenation operator so it ties two strings together.  You need an echo, print, header, or variable assignment on the whole string to make it do something.  In that other script then you could get at the variables as

```
$p = $_REQUEST['p'];
$service = $_REQUEST['service'];
```

EDIT: upon seeing the update what it is doing is using the header to redirect the script to a new page

Comment: yes that is right, and so my query is how to I recode this so that the variable values show up in the url?

Comment: I certainly wouldn't use $_REQUEST. That gets $_POST, $_GET and $_COOKIE. While the care should be in the programmer to avoid collisions, it is still a strange choice to use the catch all when you are clearly and specifically evaluating $_POST data.

Comment: I would agree except that I have seen many times when working on something that is post or get that the other call method also will occasionally be used.  By using 'request' you can be sure that you won't have to change it if you decide to test with get or make an API through post.

Comment: Not sure this guy would be doing something like that though - By the question, I would assume he is just getting started with PHP. If the code he inherited and is not fully familiar with managed to set a cookie for service - how long would he be confused before realizing that $_REQUEST['service'] was pulling from $_COOKIE as higher priority than $_POST, which is higher than $_GET? (or do i have that reversed?) It will most likely serve his needs though so I do not disagree with the answer. True though - his form is not posting to the same script so he is safe from $_GET collision.

Comment: Solved now and I am getting started with PHP but it seems my steep learning curve is because the old code this guy wrote must have had register_globals ON and so none of the code as GET or POST or REQUEST.  It has been confusing but thanks to all you guys I have made quite a leap today.